# JavaFX unable to load css file in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, windows-server-2012-r2

I wrote a simple JavaFx application that displays a table with some rows. I applied css to this application which is working fine in all local systems. When I ran this in a remote system containing Windows Server 2012 R2 the css fails to load. I can't see the colors at all on the table. I am using very dark blue in the css file but it is showing very light blue color. This program I have written in my local system and deployed into the server. I wrote another sample application in the same server with the same css file and it is working perfectly. I couldn't find what the issue is. I have even set the static content to enable on my server but the same this happens. When I removed the css file then the application is not even showing the default table in the window but only a blank page. Please help me what I am doing wrong:

**My Table class:**

```
import com.simulator.database.Records;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import org.controlsfx.control.table.TableFilter;
import quickfix.FieldNotFound;
import quickfix.Message;
import quickfix.field.Account;
import quickfix.field.OrdStatus;
import quickfix.field.OrderQty;

public class OrderHistoryTable {

    private static final TableView<Order> table = new TableView<>();
    private static final ObservableList<Order> tableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private static final TableColumn date = new TableColumn("DATE");
    private static final TableColumn exchange = new TableColumn("EXCHANGE");
    private static final TableColumn symbol = new TableColumn("SYMBOL");
    private static final TableColumn clordid = new TableColumn("CLORDID");
    private static final TableColumn qty = new TableColumn("QUANTITY");
    private static final TableColumn price = new TableColumn("PRICE");
    private static final TableColumn order_id = new TableColumn("ORDER_ID");
    private static final TableColumn account = new TableColumn("ACCOUNT");
    private static final TableColumn orderstatus = new TableColumn("ORDER STATUS");

    private TableFilter filter;

    public TableView<Order> getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    private void initializeTable() {

        date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        exchange.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("exchange"));
        symbol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("symbol"));
        clordid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("clordid"));
        qty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("qty"));
        price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        order_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("order_id"));
        account.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("account"));
        orderstatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("orderstatus"));
        date.setMaxWidth(250);
        date.setMinWidth(140);
        order_id.setMaxWidth(350.0);
        order_id.setMinWidth(140.0);
        account.setMaxWidth(250);
        account.setMinWidth(130);
        clordid.setMaxWidth(250);
        clordid.setMinWidth(120);
    }

    public void add(Message executionReport, String exchange) throws FieldNotFound {

        Order order = new Order(executionReport.getString(11), exchange, executionReport.getString(55),
                (int) executionReport.getField(new OrderQty()).getValue(), executionReport.getDouble(44),
                executionReport.getString(37), executionReport.getField(new Account()).getValue(),
                getStatus(executionReport.getField(new OrdStatus()).getValue()));
        tableList.add(order);

    }


    public String getStatus(char reportStatus) {

        switch (reportStatus) {
            case '0':
                return "NEW";
            case '2':
                return "FILLED";
            case '4':
                return "CANCELLED";
            case '5':
                return "REPLACED";
            case '8':
                return "REJECTED";
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    public void initialize() {

        initializeTable();

        table.setItems(tableList);
        table.autosize();
        table.getColumns().addAll(date, exchange, symbol, clordid, qty, price, order_id, account,
                orderstatus);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
         stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("table.css").toExternalForm());
         stage.show();


    }

}
```

**Order class**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Order {

    private final SimpleStringProperty timeStamp = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty clordid = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty exchange = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty symbol = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty account = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty orderstatus = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty qty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty price = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty order_id = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.SSS");

    public Order(String clordid, String exchange, String symbol, int qty, Double price, String order_id, String account, String orderstatus) {

        setTimeStamp();
        setClordid(clordid);
        setExchange(exchange);
        setSymbol(symbol);
        setAccount(account);
        setOrderstatus(orderstatus);
        setQty(qty);
        setPrice(price.toString());
        setOrder_Id(order_id);

    }
      public Order(String timestamp,String clordid, String exchange, String symbol, int qty, Double price, String order_id, String account, String orderstatus) {

        setTimeStamp(timestamp);
        setClordid(clordid);
        setExchange(exchange);
        setSymbol(symbol);
        setAccount(account);
        setOrderstatus(orderstatus);
        setQty(qty);
        setPrice(price.toString());
        setOrder_Id(order_id);

    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return sdf.format(timestamp);
    }

    public StringProperty order_idProperty() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public StringProperty DateProperty() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public StringProperty ExchangeProperty() {
        return exchange;
    }

    public StringProperty SymbolProperty() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public StringProperty clordidProperty() {
        return clordid;
    }

    public StringProperty AccountProperty() {
        return account;
    }

    public StringProperty OrderstatusProperty() {
        return orderstatus;
    }

    public IntegerProperty QtyProperty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public StringProperty PriceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public final String getorder_id() {
        return order_idProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getDate() {
        return DateProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getExchange() {
        return ExchangeProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getSymbol() {
        return SymbolProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getClordid() {
        return clordidProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getAccount() {
        return AccountProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getOrderstatus() {
        return OrderstatusProperty().get();
    }

    public final Integer getQty() {
        return QtyProperty().get();
    }

    public final String getPrice() {
        return PriceProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setClordid(String clordid) {
        clordidProperty().set(clordid);
    }

    public final void setTimeStamp() {

            DateProperty().setValue(getTimeStamp());

    }
    public final void setTimeStamp(String timestamp) {
        DateProperty().setValue(timestamp);
    }

    public final void setExchange(String n) {
        ExchangeProperty().set(n);
    }

    public final void setSymbol(String n) {
        SymbolProperty().set(n);
    }

    public final void setAccount(String n) {
        AccountProperty().set(n);
    }

    public final void setOrderstatus(String n) {
        OrderstatusProperty().set(n);
    }

    public final void setQty(int n) {
        QtyProperty().set(n);
    }

    public final void setPrice(String n) {
        PriceProperty().setValue(n);
    }

    public final void setOrder_Id(String n) {
       order_idProperty().setValue(n);
    }
}
```

**.css file**

```
.table .table-column{
    -fx-alignment:center;
}

.table-row-cell:disabled{
    -fx-opacity:0.5;
    -fx-background-color:darkgray;    
}


.table-cell {
   /* -fx-border-color: transparent; */
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-alignment:CENTER;
}

.table-row-cell .text{
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-fill: black;
    -fx-alignment:CENTER;
} 


.table-row-cell:hover .text , .table-row-cell:selected .text{
    -fx-fill:red;    
}

.text,.table-row-cell:focused:selected .text{

    -fx-fill:red;


}

.table-row-cell:focused:disabled{ 
    -fx-background-color:red;
}

.table-row-cell:hover , .table-row-cell:selected{

    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 1;
}
.table-row-cell:empty{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell{
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
    -fx-alignment:CENTER;
}

.table-row-cell{ 
    /*-fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;*/
    -fx-alignment:CENTER;
}
```

Actually when a user clicks a button the button action event loads this table. Please help me with this.

Comment: write `getClass().getResource("table.css").toExternalForm()` to `System.out` and check if file is present on your system.

Comment: Yes, it is giving the correct path and also it is working fine in my local system.